# Возможно ли сделать ключ необязательным полем? Django 1.6

Tags: django

Есть следующие модели:

```
class SwitchEquipment (models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'switch_equipment'
    switchequipment_networkname = models.TextField()
    switchequipment_network = models.ForeignKey(Network)


class Network(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'network'
    network_name = models.TextField()
    network_switch = models.ManyToManyField(SwitchEquipment)
```

По моей задумке поля network_switch и switchequipmet_network хочу сделать необязательными. Пробовал добавлять blank=True, но не помогло. Подскажите, возможна ли моя задумка в Django?

Comment: Вы так и не изучили ссылку, которую я вам ранее дал. Одной модели вы задаете взаимодействие многие-к-одному, второй - многие-ко-многим. Думаете это нормально?

Comment: Загляните вот сюда [очень похожий вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529472/how-do-i-make-many-to-many-field-optional-in-django)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для `m2m` поля хватит добавить `blank=True`, это сделает поле необязательным при валидации.
Для `ForeignKey`, нужно добавить `blank=True` для этих же целей и `null=True`, чтобы в базе можно было сохранять null.